# How to insert data which I get from an List into Database using Entitymanager (Hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate

I  have a List and I want to add to add the data which I get from the list into the database.
My code is:

```
List<EventPayload> mylist=eventpojo.getEventPayload();

            for(EventPayload array : mylist)
            {
                System.out.println("Comment Text :"+array.getCommentText());
                System.out.println("Comment Type :"+array.getCommentType());
                System.out.println("Comment Id :"+array.getCommentId());
                System.out.println("Email id :"+array.getComment_email());
                String email1=array.getComment_email();
                EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jcg-JPA");
                EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();


                List email=em.createQuery("SELECT usrinfo.user_id FROM UserInfo usrinfo WHERE usrinfo.email_id = :id").setParameter("id", email1).getResultList();
                String userid=email.get(0).toString();
                System.out.println("User id:"+userid);
                Date date = new Date();
                PageInfo pageinfo=new PageInfo();
                pageinfo.setComment_id(array.getCommentId());
                pageinfo.setComment_text(array.getCommentText());
                pageinfo.setComment_type(array.getCommentType());
                String date1=sdf.format(date);
                pageinfo.setCreation_date(sdf.parse(date1));
                pageinfo.setModification_date(sdf.parse(date1));
                pageinfo.setRetrospective_id(eventpojo.getEventRetrospectiveId());
                int user_id = Integer.parseInt(userid);
                pageinfo.setUser_id(user_id);
                em.persist(pageinfo);

                }
```

I have all the tables mapped with the POJOS and it is working fine.I just want to add the `CommentText` `Comment type` `comment Id` `Email Id` `Creation Date` `Modification date` and `RetrospectiveID`.I have a table PAGEINFO and also a POJO named PageInfo with these 7 fields.Kindly help

Comment: What is the  problem statement here? Is your code not working?

Comment: data is not being inserted into the database..

Comment: Can you try moving .given below statement outside of for loop.        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jcg-JPA");
                EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

Comment: When I try to initialize the entity manager out of for loop I cant access String email outside the for loop

Comment: @SumitKumar I tried it did'nt work..

Comment: Also try closing the connection em.close() and entityManagerFactory.close() after end of the loop. Keep  EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jcg-JPA"); EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); at top of for loop

Comment: Is your code running inside transaction. If not make it run under transaction. i will share the sample.

Comment: Nope..its not running under transaction..until now I only had to display data..this is the first time I have to insert data

Comment: You need transaction to persist data.

Comment: can you suggest what changes I need to make?

Comment: yes .. just 2 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the persist code inside transaction.

```
List<EventPayload> mylist=eventpojo.getEventPayload();
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jcg-JPA");

        for(EventPayload array : mylist)
        {
            System.out.println("Comment Text :"+array.getCommentText());
            System.out.println("Comment Type :"+array.getCommentType());
            System.out.println("Comment Id :"+array.getCommentId());
            System.out.println("Email id :"+array.getComment_email());
            String email1=array.getComment_email();

            EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();


            List email=em.createQuery("SELECT usrinfo.user_id FROM UserInfo usrinfo WHERE usrinfo.email_id = :id").setParameter("id", email1).getResultList();
            String userid=email.get(0).toString();
            System.out.println("User id:"+userid);
            Date date = new Date();
            PageInfo pageinfo=new PageInfo();
            pageinfo.setComment_id(array.getCommentId());
            pageinfo.setComment_text(array.getCommentText());
            pageinfo.setComment_type(array.getCommentType());
            String date1=sdf.format(date);
            pageinfo.setCreation_date(sdf.parse(date1));
            pageinfo.setModification_date(sdf.parse(date1));
            pageinfo.setRetrospective_id(eventpojo.getEventRetrospectiveId());
            int user_id = Integer.parseInt(userid);
            pageinfo.setUser_id(user_id);
            EntityTransaction  trans= entityManager.getTransaction();


            trans.begin();

            em.persist(pageinfo);

            trans.commit();
            em.close();

            }

        entityManagerFactory.close();
```